# Why system accepts without warning long int passed as int argument?

Tags: c++, integer, long-integer

Quick simple question (almost out of a curiosity):

If I declare for example in a C++ program a `long int`, and then call it in a function taking an `int`, I know it will work without any problem unless I give it a 4 byte size value which will lead to bad printing content.

However what surprises me is that it doesn't warn in any way about this. If I declare a 4 byte `long int`, the system knows that it has 32 bits to store that value. But then, if I pass that same `long int` to a function where it calls only an `int` (2 bytes), I'm assuming that I'm using 16 bits in memory that shouldn't be used by this value.

Am I right? Or will it use only the lowest 16 bits from that `long int` received as argument? What is the process here?

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int x) { // My question is why it accepts this?
    printf("%d", x);
}


int main() {
    long int y=4294967200; // 32 bits

    test(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you're talking about with an actual code sample?

Comment: edited already. My question is why it accepts passing a long int to a function that is suppose to received a int only.

Comment: This is because you have some implicit integer conversions.

Comment: Yes, but what actually happens? Does it reduce to half of the size when is received? Or just overflows the integer itself?

Comment: Just to be clear, you did compile this on a system where `long` is 64 bits, right? Because on Windows (any bittedness) or 32 bit versions of the various UNIX-alikes, `long` and `int` are typically compatible; there is no data loss (except that the literal is truncated up front).

Comment: Yes, it is on a 64 bit system, but yet I don't get what really happens, does the system reserve 64 bits when a int is declared anyway? Or as I said before it just cuts in half when received as argument? In memory space, what really happens to that variable (x) when receives another (y) that is double of the size?

Comment: Given the "32 bits" comment in `long int y=4294967200; // 32 bits`, I suspect it's because you compiled on a platform where both `int` and `long int` are 32 bits

Comment: @MiguelRuivo *Yes, it is on a 64 bit system*  Is it a Windows system?  `long int` is 32 bits on Windows in both 32- and 64-bit memory models.

Comment: No, it's Unix (Mac). However let's assume that int and long have different sizes, how does it work here?

Comment: In my example if I change the long int value to something smaller it'll print good, if I leave as it is it will give me -96 (I just don't get wha'ts happening actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's because you didn't enable that feature in your compiler. For example, using GCC with conversion warnings enabled gives:

> warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘long int’ may alter its value

If the question is why such warnings aren't enabled by default, it's because a lot of very common code patterns produce a large quantity of spurious warnings due to automatic promotions. For example, `unsigned char p[10]; ... p[1] ^= 1;`.

Comment: I am adddicted to reading your articles on global cash, currency, finanicial crime. Very rarely I see such things, which make me realize that there are still people who think.